# Como remover o hover dos itens de menu e dos botões?

Tags: java, swing

Creio que minha pergunta é bem objetiva: como remover o efeito "hover de itens do menu e de botões? Segue uma imagem do efeito hover que pretendo retirar (botão e itens de menu):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso depende muito do [**Look and Feel(LAF)**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) que estiver sendo usado na aplicação, pois geralmente é ele quem define esse tipo de característica dos componentes.

Caso não tenha modificado o que o java define por padrão(que se chama "Metal"), a forma mais simples seria alterando as propriedades específicas deste LAF:

```
UIManager.put("MenuItem.selectionBackground", UIManager.getColor("MenuItem.background"));
UIManager.put("MenuItem.selectionForeground", UIManager.getColor("MenuItem.foreground"));
```

Na verdade, isso é um "workaround" onde eu defino as mesmas cores padrões de background e foreground para as cores que seriam aplicadas quando o `JMenuItem` for selecionado. Isso causa o efeito abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Também é possivel criar a UI para o `JMenuItem` manualmente, mas particulamente acho bastante complexo de se fazer, sendo que é possível alterar com apenas duas linhas.

Caso você utilize o LAF do sistema onde a aplicação está executando, ou utilize outro como o [**Nimbus**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html), ai não te resta escolha a não ser fazer o que citei no parágrafo anterior, pois as alterações sugeridas não irão funcionar para estes dois casos.

---

E para `JButtons`, você pode utilizar o método [`setRolloverEnabled()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setRolloverEnabled-boolean-), mas vai acabar caindo no mesmo problema, pois dependendo do LAF utilizado, ele pode simplesmente ignorar esse comando e não remover o efeito.

Comment: Ok, entendi, muito obrigado pela ajuda.